# Cassandra source code ConfigurationException expection URI in cassandra.config found cassandra.yaml

Tags: cassandra, config

For my master thesis, I have to modify the source code of Cassandra. So, as suggested by https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HowToBuild, I git clone, then run ant, and everything seems nice (I managed to build the project without any error), but when I run the unitTests (cassandra/test), I have this strange error:

```
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: 
   Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config]. 
   Found[cassandra.yaml]. 
   Please prefix the file with [file:\\\] for local files and 
      [file:\\<server>\] for remote files. 
   If you are executing this from an external tool, it needs 
   to set Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.

at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:80)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:100)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:252)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.jmx.AuthorizationProxyTest.setup(AuthorizationProxyTest.java:48)"
```

I would like to test my modifications on the source code with the unitTests (because I didn't find any tutorial of how to set up cassandra from the source code on Windows, so if you have one, I would like to have the link ^^) but I didn't manage to find any solution for this bug :(. Anyone know a solution to this problem?

I am working on Windows 10 with IntelliJ and I have updated my Jdk and ant to the latest version.

Comment: Why is that error strange, it seems like a pretty normal errror message to me. Did you do what the messages tells you to do? What happened when you did so? Please update your post with the relevant information, and welcome to [so]

Comment: Well I didn't add anything to the code, so there is a cassandra.yaml in the conf subfolder (in the test), but I don't even know where the cassandra.config variable is instancied, so I have no idea where I should add the file:\\\ .

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. Those variables **("cassandra.config", "cassandra.storagedir", etc...)** are ***System variables***.

You can either set them in your code by doing something like:

```java
System.setProperty("cassandra.config", "file:///<PATH>/cassandra.yaml");
```

You can also set them whilst running the jar file:

```java
java -Dcassandra.config=file:///<PATH>/cassandra.yaml -jar <JAR>
```

Best,

Shabir

Answer (score 0):

Start a new process in jdk 1.8 and start embedded cassandra in it. and run your junit in your java version. I faced similar isue which jdk11 upgrade. Now i fixed this.

```
import org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper;
```

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EmbeddedCassandraApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra("cassandra-test.yaml");
    }
}
```