# Cassandra: Java equivalent method to `sstabledump`?

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm writing test for a java program which outputs cassandra sstable files (e.g. mc-1-big-Data.db). Now what I have is an correct output file (correct.db). To check if the program is correct or not, I need to dump the two files, and compare each field inside excep "liveness_info" (which means I cannot directly compare mc-1-big-Data.db with correct.db).

I know I can use `sstabledump` to do this. But this command runs in shell and I may not call it directly in Java since I'm supposed to do a unit test. Therefore, I'd like to have an equivalent method in Java. But after searching for a long time I still didn't find any. Could anyone give some suggestions? Thanks!

**[update]**
I've tried the method @JimWartnick mentions. When I used `SSTableExport.main(...)`, I got this error `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` caused by `org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config]. Found[cassandra.yaml]. Please prefix the file with [file:///] for local files and [file://<server>/] for remote files.`

It seems this requires me to setup cassandra server, but I suspect for a unit test I cannot do this. Any suggestions? Thanks!

**[example dump]**

Just in case it's helpful, I attach the example dump below.

```
[
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "1" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 33,
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2019-08-15T23:52:11.715Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "name", "value" : "Amy" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "2" ],
      "position" : 34
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 67,
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2019-08-15T23:52:11.738Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "name", "value" : "Bob" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "4" ],
      "position" : 68
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 103,
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2019-08-15T23:52:11.738Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "name", "value" : "Caleb" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "3" ],
      "position" : 104
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 133,
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2019-08-15T23:52:11.738Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "name", "value" : "" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Isn't sstabledump simply a call to sstableexport, which is open source? You could try to look at: https://github.com/odnoklassniki/apache-cassandra/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/SSTableExport.java

Comment: @JimWartnick Thanks for the reply! I've tried using SSTableExport.export() directly, but intellij shows there's no such a method called `export`, although I do see the `export` method marked `public` in the source code.

Comment: @JimWartnick btw I update my question in case it’s helpful.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305113/cassandra-source-code-configurationexception-expection-uri-in-cassandra-config-f